# Assigning email addresses to TFS users when not using AD

Tags: tfs

We're using a TFS setup which is a single server installation with no AD attached. I can't seem to find anywhere to administrate what email addresses users have for sendout of notifications.

Comment: I think this answer covers what you need to know: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9219527/728929

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that post. So that means there's no way to do it? Sounds pretty odd

Comment: According to the answer, your only option is to directly edit the TFS DB - which can break MS warranty & is in general considered as a *Bad* thing to do.

Comment: How do you administer your users when your TFS system is not attached to an AD? Local user definitions?

Comment: Yes, local user administration