# What is the TFS 2012 My Profile Preferred Email used for?

Tags: tfs-alerts

I am trying to get project alerts working for all of my users.  I have asked my users to set their preferred email to an internal address in their profile preferred email, but this has not worked.  I took this approach based on a previous post which indicated that the preferred email would work in tfs2012.

[Where do I administer the email addresses of TFS users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209086/where-do-i-administer-the-email-addresses-of-tfs-users?lq=1)

Comment: Is tfs configured to send alerts? In the tfs admin console

Comment: I have not been able to check.  I have the TFS powertools installed, but when I open a VS command prompt and enter tfsconfig configuremail, the command is not recognized.  Given that this is a separate issues, I'll check into this and get back with verification that the alerts are enabled.

Comment: Log onto the tfs server, open the tfs administration console. Check the settings. Subscribe to an alert and then check you receive the mail