# TFS 2013 failed build doesn't generate messages

Tags: tfs

I have TFS 2013 installation and I've set up BUILD FAILURE messages to go out to the team, but a particular build is failing and not sending out messages. How is the code mapped to a a particular Team Project? Any other ideas why this could happen?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. A repository (either Git or TFVC) exists inside a team project. Teams are a different entity, and there is no relationship between teams and code or builds -- what a team within a Team Project has access to is defined purely by security settings. Beyond that, are you talking about email notifications for build failures?

Comment: Yes - I'm talking about email notifications for build failures. So my question was about the relationship between Team Projects (where you set up the Alert) and the underlying code. I don't understand how a particular build is associated with a Team Project so that it knows which alert to send when the build fails. Really I just want to understand why messages aren't being sent ;-).

Comment: The first thing to check is that your SMTP server is correctly configured. You'll have to check the TFS Admin Console on your app tier server for that.

Comment: But I'm getting other notifications so I know that's got to be OK. I get an email from every check-in, so that's gotta be set up right. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the "**build fails**" alert works for individual user. That means send the alert to specific email address but not the Team. If that works, you can send messages to multiple people with personal alert.

Do you have a AD for your environment? you need Active Directory for team alerts to work.

As discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209086/where-do-i-administer-the-email-addresses-of-tfs-users), without Active Directory, TFS will not send team alerts. Users can set their preferred email address, which TFS will then sync to Active Directory as the "[Member's default email address]". If no Active Directory is found, that sync won't work, which means their default email is blank. Blank email means no alert sent (which means no error about the sending failing either).

You can refer to **ergohack's** answer(the last answer in the linked thread above) to check if the solution works for you.

---

If it's an AD environment, please take below things to make sure that team alerts are sent:

1. Make sure your setup is correct
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400808(v=vs.110).aspx
2. Make sure that you have the Team Project filter in your team alert
3. Enable team alerts in **Team Foundation Server Administration Console**
4. Enable team alerts with tfsconfig command prompt tool:

   `tfsconfig configuremail /Enabled:True`
5. Make sure all user names without any apostrophe or special characters, try to have only one member then test, start increasing the number of members each time with test till you get your problem.
6. Make sure your users in your AD have correct emails.
   TFS allows us to set our preferred email address for alerts, but this setting is relevant for individual alerts only!

In order to make team alerts work – verify email settings for the users in AD.

---

For further troubleshooting about TFS Notifications/Alerts you can reference below articles:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2009/10/28/tfs2010-diagnosing-email-and-soap-subscription-failures/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rihamselim/2016/08/23/troubleshooting-issues-with-visual-studio-team-services-and-tfs-notifications-alerts/

Comment: Thanks Andy. I don't have access to TFS Admin console. I figured this out by just creating personal alerts that send messages to multiple people.